# How to preserve all leading and trailing spaces?

Tags: spacing

I'm doing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\print[1]{[\texttt{#1}]}
\print{  foo    }
\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

```
[ foo ]
```

How can I make it print this:

```
[  foo    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider activating `\obeyspaces`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\print{%
  \begingroup
  \obeyspaces
  \@print
}
\newcommand{\@print}[1]{%
  [\texttt{#1}]%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\print{  foo    }

\print{ foo     }

\print{      foo}

\print{foo      }

\end{document}
```